# Create test groups in Spock

Tags: spock

Does Spock test framework provide features like test grouping that we have in TestNG? I googled around but could not find any solution.
The closest I could find is that I can define annotations in Spock and can include those in Test Runner to include/ exclude tests. However this looks more verbose than what TestNG offers.
Can someone please help? I am a novice in TestNG though I understand the unit test frameworks.

Comment: You can use anything from JUnit for grouping, for example, there was the categories concept AFAIR.